# Proving that a normal matrix minus a matrix of ones is also normal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to prove that $B = A - T$ where $A$ is normal and $T$ is a matrix of 1's is normal.

So far I have

\begin{align}
BB^* &= (A - T)(A - T)^* \\&= (A - T)(A^* - T)\\& = AA^* -TA^* - AT + T^2 \\&= A^*A - TA^* - AT + T^2\tag{by normality}\end{align}
$B^*B$ equivalently equals $A^*A -A^*T - TA + T^2.$

However I am stuck on how to show that the middle sum of the two equations are the same

Thanks

Comment: Whenever I see a matrix of ones, what I always remember is that $T=uu^T$ where $u$ is a column vector of ones. So that might be handy?

Comment: Are you sure that $T$ is "a matrix of ones" rather than the identity matrix?

Answer (score 1):

This assertion is false in general. Consider for example the matrix 
$$ U = \begin{pmatrix}
 0 &-1 \\
 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
which is unitary and thus normal. Then, we have
$$ U - T = \begin{pmatrix}
           -1 & -2 \\
           0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
which is not normal. You probably mean the identity matrix instead of the all-1s matrix!